# Historical flight departure & landing time

Tags: air-travel, airlines

I’m trying to track when United Airlines flight UA4944 from Newark (EWR) departed and landed at Albany Airport (ALB) on 26 Nov 2018.

Could anyone help me with the flight information?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/UAL4944
You may have to purchase the history.

Comment: [A Premium+ account](https://www.flightaware.com/commercial/premium/) for FlightAware is USD 39.95/month and allows you to access five months of flight history, so that would be sufficient in this case.